# SharePoint user group permission list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

How to generated an excel spreadsheet for User group permission for a specific site?

Comment: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/03/users-and-groups-permission-report.html 
Check above link, if it helps

Answer (score 0):

You could export **simple** SharePoint Users and Group Permissions to Excel via **Export to Excel** menu:

[image]

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/05/export-sharepoint-users-and-group-permissions-to-excel.html

If you want to generate **detailed** SharePoint Site Collection Permission Report to audit permissions on each and every object under a site collection like this:

[image]

Please refer to:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/02/sharepoint-site-collection-permission-report-powershell-script.html